# xcode integer shows strange values

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, integer

i created a Single View Application in XCode..
My Integer shows up strange values..
I declared the integer score with the value of 0 in the viewDidLoad method and
if two UIImageViews gets hitting each other the value of score gets every time 10 points bigger..

Game.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

int score;

@interface Game : UIViewController{
```

Game.m:

```
//score
score = 0;
Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", score];
```

Collision:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(BulletFive.frame, Asteroid.frame)){         
    BulletFive.hidden = NO;

    [self Score];
    [self PlaceAsteroid];
```

Score:

```
-(void)Score{
Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", score];
score = score + 10;

if (score > HighScore) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
   }
}
```

My problem: 
If I click on a store button in the main menu and go to the game again, it shows up very strange values ​​like 16060 or 26110 in a UILabel. The storebutton has nothing to do with the other view controller. What could be wrong or what is wrong with XCode ? 
Sorry for my english, Google Translator isn´t very helpful..

Comment: It's really hard to answer specific questions like this abstractly. In order to help, we'll need to see a small, self-contained example (http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

when you declare the int or NSInteger make sure, it's not a pointer.

Wrong :

```
int *variable1;
NSInteger *variable1;
```

Right one:

```
int variable1;
NSInteger variable1;
```

Please add more description, so I can help you further.

Comment: make sure, you r using %d for integer instead of %i